# How to Get-AzPublicIpAddress based on ResourceId?

Tags: azure, powershell

Deployment script needs to enumerate existing public IP addresses from public IP prefix. Public IP Prefix object contains an array of resource identifies of individual public IP address.

I'd like to retrieve individual public ip addresses using provided resource identifier. Something like this:

```
Get-AzPublicIpAddress -ResourceId $resourceId;
```

Unfortunately, such signature doesn't exist. Get-AzPublicIpAddress expects ip address name as input parameter.

I understand that I can do:

1. Call Get-AzResource and get needed information from returned object [it means extra network call]
2. Parse needed information out of resource identifier [would like to avoid implementing this logic in PowerShell]

Question - are these the only options? Or maybe Az provides a built-in way of parsing resource identifiers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use `Get-AzResource -resourceId xxx -ExpandProperties | fl *` for such requests. its a generic cmdlet that will work for any resource.

How is calling `Get-AzResource` an extra network call, compared to `Get-AzPublicIpAddress`? Its 1 call vs 1 call.

2. No, Az doesnt provide any parsing capabilities, they are not needed. You have tools to use resource id as well as individual names.

getting resource name out of resource id is fairly easy:

```
$resourceId -split '/' | Select-Object -Last 1
```

Comment: Get-AzResource doesn't retrieve resource-specific data (or it is not clear how to access it). I'd like to avoid taking dependency on format of resource id.

Comment: resource id format wont change, if it will - everything will break, this bit will be your last concern. also, check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can pass the `-ResourceId` directly to the command, all the built-in parameters are here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/get-azpublicipaddress?view=azps-1.4.0. The most close way I can find is your option 2.

Not sure why you want to use `Get-AzPublicIpAddress` via `ResourceId`, even if we use `-Name`  and `-ResourceGroupName`  i.e. `Get-AzPublicIpAddress -Name <publicIpName> -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName>`, it essentially also passes them into the request url of the [rest api which the command called](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/virtualnetwork/publicipaddress(preview)/get).

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/joywebapp/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/joyVM-ip?api-version=2018-10-01
```

Actually, you could find `/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/joywebapp/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/joyVM-ip` is the `ResourceId`.

So I think it should be not too difficult for Microsoft to add the `-ResourceId` as a bulit-in parameter of the `Get-AzPublicIpAddress` command, if you want to improve it, you could give the feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback).

**Update**:

Microsoft has replied to the this issue, see : https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/8704#issuecomment-470604852

> thanks for opening this feature request -- to provide more insight as to why the issues you mentioned above were closed: all new cmdlets that we ship in Az must conform to the pattern of having parameter sets that allow the user to do the following:
>
> Provide the components of a resource (e.g., resource group name, resource name, etc.)
> Provide the resource id of a resource
> Provide the object representation of the resource (some cmdlets won't use this, like Get-*)
>
> Later this year, we will begin generating our cmdlets using AutoRest ([see this blog post for more details](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/cmdlets-via-autorest/)), and the above patterns will be enforced in the generator. Our goal then is to generate cmdlets for existing Azure services and replace our existing cmdlets with the generated ones.

Comment: Thank you Joy. Yes, I understand the structure of Resource Id and understand that i can easily find all needed information from Resource Id. I'll also create an issue on their GitHub page for Az package. Hopefully they'll provide some parse functionality...

Comment: Created a new issue in their github: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/8704.

Comment: @ZakiMa Hi, even if it is not the result you expect, but I think my reply answered your question, could you accept it as the answer? thanks.

Comment: @ZakiMa Microsoft has replied to your github issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/8704#issuecomment-470604852 , updated my reply.